# Objective-C String(yyyy-mm-dd) to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, ios5

My App is a JSON code which involves a date in string type. (Such as "2011-10-01").
I would like to know how I could conver it into NSDate?
It needs to be displayed in a different time format such as "1 October, 2011".

ex. this code doesn't work:

```
   NSString *date1 = @"2010-11-12";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMMM-dd"];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:date1];
    NSString *strdate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? If the problem is just that `strdate` ends up in the same format as the original, it's because you're using the same formatter. Use a second formatter with a different format if you want `strdate` to look different from `date1`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Tug writes in [his blog post on the subject](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2011/01/ios-101-how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate.html):

> Objective-C and iOS SDK provide a class to help formatting date
>   (marshaling and unmarshaling), this class is [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). No
>   surprise, the NSDateFormatter uses the [Unicode Date Format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns)
>   Patterns.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:publicationDate ];
[dateFormatter release];
```

where publicationDate in this case is an NSString.

Comment: Thanks works great. Don't need the release line with ARC. Just to help future rookies like me.

Comment: Did any one notice or it is me only that, this code decrements date by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSDateFormatter`. The appropriate method is `dateFromString:`. Take a look at the documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];    

NSString *todayString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDate *someDate=[NSDate date];

NSString *targetDateString = [df stringFromDate:someDate];

NSLog(@"date:%@",targetDateString);
```